# Gantt for the Matrix Visual to show the line of activity for project

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a below table and need a Dax code to produce a Gantt line using Matrix visual. Code should show the line of activity of investment stops and O&M starts . I have tried using if condition with a logic to check which years have more value greater then 0 show 1 and 0 will show 0.

[image]

Result should something like below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure with:

```
HasAmount = 
  var a = SUM('YourTable'[Amount])
  return IF(a <> 0, 1, 0)
```

[image]

You can also achieve the above without needing a measure. Just use `Amount` in the Values of the Matrix. Then use conditional formatting.

Comment: Thanks it worked i used below code but getting 1 for both investment and OM even when is 0 Total Measure = 
VAR InvestmentValue = CALCULATE(SUM('PNB'[Amount]), 'PNB'[Type] = "Investment")
VAR OMValue = CALCULATE(SUM('PNB'[Amount]), 'PNB'[Type] = "O&M")

RETURN
    IF(InvestmentValue > 0 && OMValue > 0, 2, IF(InvestmentValue > 0 || OMValue > 0, 1, 0))